# What is the role of L1 and L2 in the following ASK transmitter circuit?

Tags: rf, oscillator, transmitter, resonator

I know almost nothing about how oscillators work. Please explain about the operation of the circuit below (ASK transmitter module), especially the inductors.
Is it possible to replace these two inductors with SMD inductors?[image]

Comment: What research have you done to answer this question for yourself? If you google FS1000A there's lots of data out there., even an article under the heading "How does a 433 MHz transmitter work?"

Comment: 2SC3357 is NPN transistor not PNP like in schematic. So this is a wrong picture and wrong emitter collector disposition.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's photo shows significant coupling between one coil and the other through the air. This kind of coupling would be greatly reduced if coils were to be substituted with SMD components.

So one asks, " is this air-coupling important for transmitter operation?"
Other similar transmitter modules mount these two inductors at right angles, which reduces coupling quite a bit - yet they still operate. A simulation also suggests that 433 MHz oscillations are possible with no coil air-coupling. So it would seem that SMD inductors should work, if appropriate values are chosen.

There **are** subtle possibilities that may be in-play. One wishes to avoid sending frequencies to the antenna other than 433 MHz., such as harmonics. It is possible that air-coupling *might* reduce harmonics - but not likely...since the designer has no control whatsoever of the kind of antenna a user might attach.

---

BTW: OP's schematic incorrectly shows oscillating transistor Q2 with emitter toward Vcc...it is backwards.